# Black Youtube video over Google Maps v3 infowindow!

Tags: youtube, maps

Ive got this very strange problem related to google maps and youtube. I have embedded a youtube video in an iframe. and i have embed that iframe in an info window. Now the problem is that when i run it on firefox, the video shows up black. on chrome, its distorted. but when i open that iframe in separate tab. the video is just fine!

Anyone else having this problem?

I have tried the same in Google Maps v2 and its working good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an open issue at Google Maps v3 !
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3160

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I have been following this issue for a very long time now. Using the HTML 5 option of embedding a Youtube video and putting wmode=opaque and autoplay=1 and using the latest browsers from FF, IE, Safari and Chrome everything works fine / great. Problem is, intermittently, in FF a video shows up with audio only. This happens say 1 out of 10 times (meaning in 9 cases Youtube video + audio, in 1 case Youtube audio only). Clicking on the dark region brings full screen where video is visible ! I am yet to find out a pattern to diagnose this problem. Else, things are much better now. I am doing like what you are. Clicking on a marker on Maps V3 opens up an iframe. Inside that iframe i call a Youtube video using the iframe embed option. Maps V2, no problem !!!